# How to organize separate client and server repositories for both development and deployment?

Tags: node.js, git, express, gruntjs, gulp

I've been developing a client/server application (React/Express) as a single repository up until now. This made it straightforward to either run the server in development mode using the raw web app code/assets for debugging on both client and server, or production mode with a built web app.

Now it seems that there should be two repositories because the server API is actually being used by much more than my React app and it isn't acceptable to have the two so intertwined.

I'm not sure how to go about refactoring this. I know I basically want a directory on the server that will act as a deploy target for the production-ready React app. However, I don't know how organize everything so that I can easily  start the server in development mode and have my raw web app code be continually watched and compiled.

The best I've come up with at this point is to just have two different directories in the server repository, one for production builds (the built code and assets are copied to here) and one for running the server in dev mode where my raw app code is continually copied from the client repository during development.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

A typical workflow in git is to have a development server that uses continuous integration to upload commits as they are made, and then a production server that you manually deploy to with a commit that is deemed "release ready" from the development server.

Having two directories that basically act as a development and production server is an acceptable practice, IMO. You should run the server in production and dev mode at all times, ideally, meaning that you would run dev and prod on different ports.o

More of an opinion than a firm answer, but that's my 2 cents.

Comment: Thanks for the 2 cents. It does help to get a second opinion.